# resample - can't create training and test sets separately

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, resampling

I'm using the bootstrapping technique to evaluate a `MLPClassifier` and i am using `scikit.utils.resample` to get different random samples, but the `x_test` and `y_test` are returning empty:

```py
seeds = [50,51,52,53,54]
for i in range(5): # number of bootstrap samples
    X_train, y_train = resample(X, y, n_samples=len(X), random_state=seeds[i], stratify=y)
    X_test = [x for x in X if x not in X_train] # test = samples that weren't selected for train
    y_test = [y for y in y if y not in y_train] # test = samples that weren't selected for train

    X_test
    # []
```

What am i doing wrong? / Is there a better way of doing this? It's hard to believe that `sklearn` doesn't provide a better approach.

Comment: Are your initial `X` and `y` lists, or numpy arrays?

Comment: `X` and `y` are numpy arrays

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: I will test, i maybe got something wrong because `y_test` is empty.

Comment: Have made some slight corrections in my answer below - `y_test` doesn't need conversion to list, and it should work as is (provided that it is indeed a 1D numpy array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first list comprehension will not work here, since the `in` operator does not work for 2D numpy arrays.

Let's first reproduce your issue with dummy data:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1., 0.], [2., 1.], [0., 0.]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2])

X_train, y_train = resample(X, y, random_state=0)
X_train
# result
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

So far so good; but, as I said, the list comprehension will not work, as you have already found yourself:

```
X_test = [x for x in X if x not in X_train]
X_test
# []
```

the reason being that the `in` operator will not work for 2D numpy arrays.

Converting your initial `X` to list resolves the issue:

```
X = X.tolist()

X_train, y_train = resample(X, y, random_state=0)
X_train
# [[1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]] # as previous result
X_test = [x for x in X if x not in X_train]
X_test
# [[0.0, 0.0]]
```

where, as expected, we get in `X_test` the only element of the initial `X` not present in `X_train`, i.e. `[[0.0, 0.0]]`.

On the contrary, `y` being a 1D numpy array, the `in` operator in the list comprehension will work:

```
y_test = [y for y in y if y not in y_train]
y_test
# [2]
```

Comment: That sounds nice, but in my actual data it throws this error: `TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Comment: @joann2555 Have you imported numpy? If yes, please edit your post to include a sample of your initial `X` data.

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. But another issue comes out: shall i split `x`and `y` before bootstrapping? If i split before, `y_test` will always be empty.

Comment: @joann2555 sorry, I don't get you; the way you are using `resample`, your `y_test` will never be empty. In any case, comments are not the right place for such follow-up questions, irrelevant to the OP; if the answer resolved the specific coding issue you were facing, kindly accept it, and you are always very welcome to open a new question with possible new issues.